# How to more efficiently test if data anomalies occur in transaction (Django)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, testing, data-anomalies

I want to test if **data anomalies** such as **dirty read**, **non-repeatable read**, **phantom read**, **lost update** and so on occur in transaction.

Actually, I used **`person` table** which has **`id`** and **`name`** as shown below.

#### `person` table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| **1** | **John** |
| **2** | **David** |

Then, I tested **non-repeatable read** with **`test` view** below and **one command prompt**. *During **`sleep(10)`**, **one command prompt** updates **"David"** to **"Tom"** and commits:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from .models import Person
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.db import transaction
from time import sleep

@transaction.atomic
def test(request):
    print(Person.objects.get(pk=2)) # "David"
    sleep(10) # Update "David" to "Tom" and commit by one command prompt.
    print(Person.objects.get(pk=2)) # "Tom"

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

But, every time I test **data anomalies**, I manually need to run **`test` view** and update and commit with **one command prompt** which takes much time.

So, how can I **more efficiently** test if **data anomalies** occur in transaction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple concurrent database transactions with Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22518156/multiple-concurrent-database-transactions-with-django)

Answer (score 1):

With **threads**, you can more efficiently test if **data anomalies** occur in transaction.

I created 5 sets of code with threads to test 5 common data anomalies **dirty read**, **non-repeatable read**, **phantom read**, **lost update** and **write skew** with the Django's default isolation level **READ COMMITTED** and **PostgreSQL** as shown below. ***Lost update** or **write skew** occurs by race condition and I used **PostgreSQL**.

I explain about:

- **dirty read** => [**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18297626/difference-between-non-repeatable-read-vs-dirty-read/73811476#73811476)
- **non-repeatable read** and **phantom read** => [**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043712/what-is-the-difference-between-non-repeatable-read-and-phantom-read/73812058#73812058)
- **lost update** and **write skew** => [**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826714/lost-update-vs-write-skew/73847878#73847878)
- which **anomaly** occurs in which **isolation level** => [**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165438/dirty-reads-in-postgres/73995828#73995828)

### <**Dirty read**>, <**Non-repeatable read**> and <**Phantom read**>

First, I created **`store_person` table** with **`id`** and **`name`** with **`models.py`** as shown below:

#### `store_person` table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| **1** | **John** |
| **2** | **David** |

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Then, I created and ran the test code of **dirty read** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.db import transaction
from time import sleep
from .models import Person
from threading import Thread
from django.http import HttpResponse

@transaction.atomic
def transaction1(flow):
    while True:
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 1":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("<T1", flow[0] + ">", "BEGIN")
                flow[0] = "Step 2"
                break
        
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 2":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("<T1", flow[0] + ">", "SELECT")
                person = Person.objects.get(id=2)
                print(person.id, person.name)
                flow[0] = "Step 3"
                break

        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 5":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("<T1", flow[0] + ">", "SELECT")
                person = Person.objects.get(id=2)
                print(person.id, person.name)
                flow[0] = "Step 6"
                break
        
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 6":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("<T1", flow[0] + ">", "COMMIT")
                flow[0] = "Step 7"
                break
        break

@transaction.atomic
def transaction2(flow):
    while True:
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 3":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("<T2", flow[0] + ">", "BEGIN")
                flow[0] = "Step 4"
                break

        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 4":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("<T2", flow[0] + ">", "UPDATE")
                Person.objects.filter(id=2).update(name="Tom")
                flow[0] = "Step 5"
                break
        
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 7":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("<T2", flow[0] + ">", "COMMIT")
                break
        break

def call_transcations(request): 
    flow = ["Step 1"]

    thread1 = Thread(target=transaction1, args=(flow,), daemon=True)
    thread2 = Thread(target=transaction2, args=(flow,), daemon=True)

    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()

    thread1.join()
    thread2.join()

    return HttpResponse("Call_transcations")
```

Then, **dirty read** didn't occur according to the result belew on console because in any isolation levels in **PostgreSQL**, **dirty read** doesn't happen:

```
<T1 Step 1> BEGIN
<T1 Step 2> SELECT
2 David # Here
<T2 Step 3> BEGIN
<T2 Step 4> UPDATE
<T1 Step 5> SELECT
2 David # Here
<T1 Step 6> COMMIT
<T2 Step 7> COMMIT
```

And also, I could get **the PostgreSQL query logs** below. You can check [**how to log PostgreSQL queries**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54780698/postgresql-database-log-transaction/73432601#73432601):

```
[23576]: BEGIN
[23576]: SELECT "store_person"."id", "store_person"."name" 
         FROM "store_person" 
         WHERE "store_person"."id" = 2 
         LIMIT 21
[8600]: BEGIN
[8600]: UPDATE "store_person" SET "name" = 'Tom' 
        WHERE "store_person"."id" = 2
[23576]: SELECT "store_person"."id", "store_person"."name" 
         FROM "store_person" 
         WHERE "store_person"."id" = 2 
         LIMIT 21
[23576]: COMMIT
[8600]: COMMIT
```

And, this table below shows the flow and SQL query logs of PostgreSQL above:

| Flow | Transaction 1 (T1) | Transaction 2 (T2) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Step 1** | **`BEGIN;`** |  | **T1 starts.** |
| **Step 2** | **`SELECT "store_person"."id", "store_person"."name" FROM "store_person" WHERE "store_person"."id" = 2 LIMIT 21;`** **2 David** |  | **T1 reads `David`.** |
| **Step 3** |  | **`BEGIN;`** | **T2 starts.** |
| **Step 4** |  | **`UPDATE "store_person" SET "name" = 'Tom' WHERE "store_person"."id" = 2;`** | **T2 updates `David` to `Tom`.** |
| **Step 5** | **`SELECT "store_person"."id", "store_person"."name" FROM "store_person" WHERE "store_person"."id" = 2 LIMIT 21;`** **2 David** |  | **T1 reads `David` instead of `Tom` before T2 commits.** #### ***Dirty read doesn't occur!!** |
| **Step 6** | **`COMMIT;`** |  | **T1 commits.** |
| **Step 7** |  | **`COMMIT;`** | **T2 commits.** |

Next, I created and ran the test code of **non-repeatable read** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

# ...

@transaction.atomic
def transaction1(flow):
    while True:
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 1":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("<T1", flow[0] + ">", "BEGIN")
                flow[0] = "Step 2"
                break
        
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 2":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("<T1", flow[0] + ">", "SELECT")
                person = Person.objects.get(id=2)
                print(person.id, person.name)
                flow[0] = "Step 3"
                break

        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 6":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("<T1", flow[0] + ">", "SELECT")                
                person = Person.objects.get(id=2)
                print(person.id, person.name)
                flow[0] = "Step 7"
                break
        
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 7":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("<T1", flow[0] + ">", "COMMIT")
                break
        break

@transaction.atomic
def transaction2(flow):
    while True:
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 3":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("<T2", flow[0] + ">", "BEGIN")
                flow[0] = "Step 4"
                break

        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 4":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("<T2", flow[0] + ">", "UPDATE")
                Person.objects.filter(id=2).update(name="Tom")
                flow[0] = "Step 5"
                break
        
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 5":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("<T2", flow[0] + ">", "COMMIT")
                flow[0] = "Step 6"
                break
        break

# ...
```

Then, **non-repeatable read** occurred according to the result belew on console because in **READ COMMITTED** isolation level in **PostgreSQL**, **non-repeatable read** occurs:

```
<T1 Step 1> BEGIN
<T1 Step 2> SELECT
2 David # Here
<T2 Step 3> BEGIN
<T2 Step 4> UPDATE
<T2 Step 5> COMMIT
<T1 Step 6> SELECT
2 Tom # Here
<T1 Step 7> COMMIT
```

And also, I could get **the PostgreSQL query logs** below:

```
[23128]: BEGIN
[23128]: SELECT "store_person"."id", "store_person"."name" 
         FROM "store_person" 
         WHERE "store_person"."id" = 2 
         LIMIT 21
[6368]: BEGIN
[6368]: UPDATE "store_person" SET "name" = 'Tom' 
        WHERE "store_person"."id" = 2
[6368]: COMMIT
[23128]: SELECT "store_person"."id", "store_person"."name" 
         FROM "store_person" 
         WHERE "store_person"."id" = 2 
         LIMIT 21
[23128]: COMMIT
```

And, this table below shows the flow and SQL query logs of PostgreSQL above:

| Flow | Transaction 1 (T1) | Transaction 2 (T2) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Step 1** | **`BEGIN;`** |  | **T1 starts.** |
| **Step 2** | **`SELECT "store_person"."id", "store_person"."name" FROM "store_person" WHERE "store_person"."id" = 2 LIMIT 21;`** **2 David** |  | **T1 reads `David`.** |
| **Step 3** |  | **`BEGIN;`** | **T2 starts.** |
| **Step 4** |  | **`UPDATE "store_person" SET "name" = 'Tom' WHERE "store_person"."id" = 2;`** | **T2 updates `David` to `Tom`.** |
| **Step 5** |  | **`COMMIT;`** | **T2 commits.** |
| **Step 6** | **`SELECT "store_person"."id", "store_person"."name" FROM "store_person" WHERE "store_person"."id" = 2 LIMIT 21;`** **2 Tom** |  | **T1 reads `Tom` instead of `David` after T2 commits.** #### ***Non-repeatable read occurs!!** |
| **Step 7** | **`COMMIT;`** |  | **T1 commits.** |

Next, I created and ran the test code of **phantom read** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

# ...

@transaction.atomic
def transaction1(flow):
    while True:
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 1":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("<T1", flow[0] + ">", "BEGIN")
                flow[0] = "Step 2"
                break
        
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 2":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("<T1", flow[0] + ">", "SELECT")
                persons = Person.objects.all()
                for person in persons:
                    print(person.id, person.name)
                flow[0] = "Step 3"
                break

        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 6":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("<T1", flow[0] + ">", "SELECT")                
                persons = Person.objects.all()
                for person in persons:
                    print(person.id, person.name)
                flow[0] = "Step 7"
                break
        
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 7":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("<T1", flow[0] + ">", "COMMIT")
                break
        break

@transaction.atomic
def transaction2(flow):
    while True:
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 3":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("<T2", flow[0] + ">", "BEGIN")
                flow[0] = "Step 4"
                break

        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 4":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("<T2", flow[0] + ">", "INSERT")
                Person.objects.create(id=3, name="Tom")
                flow[0] = "Step 5"
                break
        
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 5":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("<T2", flow[0] + ">", "COMMIT")
                flow[0] = "Step 6"
                break
        break

# ...
```

Then, **phantom read** occurred according to the result belew on console because in **READ COMMITTED** isolation level in **PostgreSQL**, **phantom read** occurs:

```
<T1 Step 1> BEGIN
<T1 Step 2> SELECT
1 John # Here
2 David # Here
<T2 Step 3> BEGIN
<T2 Step 4> INSERT
<T2 Step 5> COMMIT
<T1 Step 6> SELECT
1 John # Here
2 David # Here
3 Tom # Here
<T1 Step 7> COMMIT
```

And also, I could get **the PostgreSQL query logs** below:

```
[15912]: BEGIN
[15912]: SELECT "store_person"."id", "store_person"."name" 
         FROM "store_person"
[2098]: BEGIN
[2098]: INSERT INTO "store_person" ("id", "name") 
        VALUES (3, 'Tom') 
        RETURNING "store_person"."id"
[2098]: COMMIT
[15912]: SELECT "store_person"."id", "store_person"."name" 
         FROM "store_person"
[15912]: COMMIT
```

And, this table below shows the flow and SQL query logs of PostgreSQL above:

| Flow | Transaction 1 (T1) | Transaction 2 (T2) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Step 1** | **`BEGIN;`** |  | **T1 starts.** |
| **Step 2** | **`SELECT "store_person"."id", "store_person"."name" FROM "store_person";`** **1 John** **2 David** |  | **T1 reads 2 rows.** |
| **Step 3** |  | **`BEGIN;`** | **T2 starts.** |
| **Step 4** |  | **`INSERT INTO "store_person" ("id", "name") VALUES (3, 'Tom') RETURNING "store_person"."id";`** | **T2 inserts the row with `3` and `Tom` to `person` table.** |
| **Step 5** |  | **`COMMIT;`** | **T2 commits.** |
| **Step 6** | **`SELECT "store_person"."id", "store_person"."name" FROM "store_person";`** **1 John** **2 David** **3 Tom** |  | **T1 reads 3 rows instead of 2 rows after T2 commits.** #### *Phantom read occurs!! |
| **Step 7** | **`COMMIT;`** |  | **T1 commits.** |

### <**Lost update**>

First, I created **`store_product` table** with **`id`**, **`name`** and **`stock`** with **`models.py`** as shown below:

#### `store_product` table:

| id | name | stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Apple** | **10** |
| **2** | **Orange** | **20** |

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    stock = models.IntegerField()
```

```py
# "store/views.py"

# ...

@transaction.atomic
def transaction1(flow):
    while True:
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 1":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("T1", flow[0], "BEGIN")
                flow[0] = "Step 2"
                break
        
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 2":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("T1", flow[0], "SELECT")
                product = Product.objects.get(id=2)
                print(product.id, product.name, product.stock)
                flow[0] = "Step 3"
                break

        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 5":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("T1", flow[0], "UPDATE")
                Product.objects.filter(id=2).update(stock=13)
                flow[0] = "Step 6"
                break
        
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 6":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("T1", flow[0], "COMMIT")
                flow[0] = "Step 7"
                break
        break

@transaction.atomic
def transaction2(flow):
    while True:
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 3":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("T2", flow[0], "BEGIN")
                flow[0] = "Step 4"
                break

        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 4":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("T2", flow[0], "SELECT")
                product = Product.objects.get(id=2)
                print(product.id, product.name, product.stock)
                flow[0] = "Step 5"
                break
        
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 7":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("T2", flow[0], "UPDATE")
                Product.objects.filter(id=2).update(stock=16)
                flow[0] = "Step 8"
                break

        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 8":
                sleep(0.1)
                print("T2", flow[0], "COMMIT")
                break
        break

# ...
```

Then, **lost update** occurred according to the result belew on console because in **READ COMMITTED** isolation level in **PostgreSQL**, **lost update** occurs:

```
T1 Step 1 BEGIN
T1 Step 2 SELECT # Reads the same row
2 Orange 20
T2 Step 3 BEGIN
T2 Step 4 SELECT # Reads the same row
2 Orange 20
T1 Step 5 UPDATE # Writes "stock"
T1 Step 6 COMMIT # And commits the write
T2 Step 7 UPDATE # Overwrites "stock"
T2 Step 8 COMMIT # And commits the overwrite
```

And also, I could get **the PostgreSQL query logs** below:

```
[20504]: BEGIN
[20504]: SELECT "store_product"."id", "store_product"."name", "store_product"."stock" 
         FROM "store_product" 
         WHERE "store_product"."id" = 2 
         LIMIT 21
[3840]: BEGIN
[3840]: SELECT "store_product"."id", "store_product"."name", "store_product"."stock" 
        FROM "store_product" 
        WHERE "store_product"."id" = 2 
        LIMIT 21
[20504]: UPDATE "store_product" SET "stock" = 13 
         WHERE "store_product"."id" = 2
[20504]: COMMIT
[3840]: UPDATE "store_product" SET "stock" = 16 
        WHERE "store_product"."id" = 2
[3840]: COMMIT
```

And, this table below shows the flow and SQL query logs of PostgreSQL above:

| Flow | Transaction 1 (T1) | Transaction 2 (T2) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Step 1** | **`BEGIN;`** |  | **T1 starts.** |
| **Step 2** | **`SELECT "store_product"."id", "store_product"."name", "store_product"."stock" FROM "store_product" WHERE "store_product"."id" = 2 LIMIT 21;`** **2 Orange 20** |  | **T1 reads `20` which is updated later to `13` because a customer buys 7 oranges.** |
| **Step 3** |  | **`BEGIN;`** | **T2 starts.** |
| **Step 4** |  | **`SELECT "store_product"."id", "store_product"."name", "store_product"."stock" FROM "store_product" WHERE "store_product"."id" = 2 LIMIT 21;`** **2 Orange 20** | **T2 reads `20` which is updated later to `16` because a customer buys 4 oranges.** |
| **Step 5** | **`UPDATE "store_product" SET "stock" = 13 WHERE "store_product"."id" = 2;`** |  | **T1 updates `20` to `13`.** |
| **Step 6** | **`COMMIT;`** |  | **T1 commits.** |
| **Step 7** |  | **`UPDATE "store_product" SET "stock" = 16 WHERE "store_product"."id" = 2;`** | **T2 updates `13` to `16` after T1 commits.** |
| **Step 8** |  | **`COMMIT;`** | **T2 commits.** #### *Lost update occurs. |

### <**Write skew**>

First, I created **`store_doctor` table** with **`id`**, **`name`** and **`on_call`** with **`models.py`** as shown below:

#### `store_doctor` table:

| id | name | on_call |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **John** | **True** |
| **2** | **Lisa** | **True** |

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    on_call = models.BooleanField()
```

```py
# "store/views.py"

# ...

@transaction.atomic
def transaction1(flow):
    while True:
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 1":
                print("T1", flow[0], "BEGIN")
                flow[0] = "Step 2"
                break
        
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 2":
                print("T1", flow[0], "SELECT")
                doctor_count = Doctor.objects.filter(on_call=True).count()
                print(doctor_count)
                flow[0] = "Step 3"
                break

        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 5":
                print("T1", flow[0], "UPDATE")
                Doctor.objects.filter(id=1).update(on_call=False)
                flow[0] = "Step 6"
                break
        
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 6":
                print("T1", flow[0], "COMMIT")
                flow[0] = "Step 7"
                break
        break

@transaction.atomic
def transaction2(flow):
    while True:
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 3":
                print("T2", flow[0], "BEGIN")
                flow[0] = "Step 4"
                break

        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 4":
                print("T2", flow[0], "SELECT")
                doctor_count = Doctor.objects.filter(on_call=True).count()
                print(doctor_count)
                flow[0] = "Step 5"
                break
        
        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 7":
                print("T2", flow[0], "UPDATE")
                Doctor.objects.filter(id=2).update(on_call=False)
                flow[0] = "Step 8"
                break

        while True:
            if flow[0] == "Step 8":
                print("T2", flow[0], "COMMIT")
                break
        break

# ...
```

Then, **write skew** occurred according to the result belew on console because in **READ COMMITTED** isolation level in **PostgreSQL**, **write skew** occurs:

```
T1 Step 1 BEGIN
T1 Step 2 SELECT # Reads the same data
2 
T2 Step 3 BEGIN
T2 Step 4 SELECT # Reads the same data
2
T1 Step 5 UPDATE # Writes 'False' to John's "on_call" 
T1 Step 6 COMMIT # And commits the write
T2 Step 7 UPDATE # Writes 'False' to Lisa's "on_call" 
T2 Step 8 COMMIT # And commits the write
```

And also, I could get **the PostgreSQL query logs** below:

```
[11252]: BEGIN
[11252]: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" 
         FROM "store_doctor" 
         WHERE "store_doctor"."on_call"
[2368]: BEGIN
[2368]: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" 
        FROM "store_doctor" 
        WHERE "store_doctor"."on_call"
[11252]: UPDATE "store_doctor" 
         SET "on_call" = false 
         WHERE "store_doctor"."id" = 1
[11252]: COMMIT
[2368]: UPDATE "store_doctor" 
        SET "on_call" = false 
        WHERE "store_doctor"."id" = 2
[2368]: COMMIT
```

And, this table below shows the flow and SQL query logs of PostgreSQL above:

| Flow | Transaction 1 (T1) | Transaction 2 (T2) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Step 1** | **`BEGIN;`** |  | **T1 starts.** |
| **Step 2** | **`SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "store_doctor" WHERE "store_doctor"."on_call";`** **2** |  | **T1 reads `2` so John can take a rest.** |
| **Step 3** |  | **`BEGIN;`** | **T2 starts.** |
| **Step 4** |  | **`SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "store_doctor" WHERE "store_doctor"."on_call";`** **2** | **T2 reads `2` so Lisa can take a rest.** |
| **Step 5** | **`UPDATE "store_doctor" SET "on_call" = false WHERE "store_doctor"."id" = 1;`** |  | **T1 updates `True` to `False` which means John takes a rest.** |
| **Step 6** | **`COMMIT;`** |  | **T1 commits.** |
| **Step 7** |  | **`UPDATE "store_doctor" SET "on_call" = false WHERE "store_doctor"."id" = 2;`** | **T2 updates `True` to `False` which means Lisa takes a rest.** |
| **Step 8** |  | **`COMMIT;`** | **T2 commits.** #### John and Lisa both take a rest. #### *Write skew occurs. |